# Create a diagonal matrix from a dataframe in r

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse

I have this data frame:

[image]

```
data.frame(Name = c("A", "B"), 
           Value = c(1,2))
```

and I would like to arrive at a matrix with `Name` values as the matrix's row names and column names and values as the product of a subtraction like the following

[image]

AKA

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `outer` -

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B"), Value = c(1,2))
mat <- t(outer(df$Value, df$Value, `-`))
dimnames(mat) <- list(df$Name, df$Name)
mat

#   A B
#A  0 1
#B -1 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I assumed you wanted it done with matrix operations, so here's my effort.

```
 dd <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B"), 
            Value = c(1,2))
 M <- matrix( dd$Value, 2,2, dimnames=list( dd$Name, dd$Name))
 M
#  A B
#A 1 1
$B 2 2

M - t(M)
#  A  B
#A 0 -1
#B 1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B"), value = c(1,2))

df |> 
  bind_cols(df |> pivot_wider()) |> 
  transmute(across(A:B, \(x) x - value))

   A B
1  0 1
2 -1 0
```

*Note `name` and `value` are lowercase in this example. If they are capitalized or if there are other column names, use the `names_from` and `values_from` args in `pivot_wider()`.
Example: `pivot_wider(names_from = 'Name', values_from = "Value")`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach with `col()` for indexing:

```r
mat <- array(df$Value, rep(nrow(df), 2), dimnames = list(df$Name, df$Name))
df$Value[col(mat)] - mat

#    A B
# A  0 1
# B -1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Isnt this just?

```
col(df) - df$value

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]   -1    0

with(df, structure(col(df) - value, .Dimnames = list(name, name)))
   A B
A  0 1
B -1 0
```